# Creating specific lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I've been working on this code for a while now, and am very slow at this point. I don't know if the answer is obvious, but I haven't been able to think of a way to convert this bit:

```
foreach (Item i in stockList)
{
    if (i == order.OrderItem)
        i.ChangeStock(order.NumberOfItems);
}
outStandingOrders.Remove(order);
```

into a lambda expression. The best I could come up with is

`stockList.ForEach(i => i == order.OrderItem)`

(Don't know where to go from here)

There is also only ever one item in stockList that is equal to order.OrderItem.

Any help would be hot

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to lambda?

Comment: It should be cleaner and I don't know how, so that makes me curious. Based off of the documentation it should be possible.

Comment: Why should it be cleaner? The code looks pretty good to me.

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner, I guess that's not the case. Normally it cleans up fairly well. I'm also trying to become more familiar with lambdas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing on your information that *"There is also only ever one item in stockList that is equal to order.OrderItem"*, I would write it simply:

```
 var item = stockList.FirstOrDefault(i => i == order.OrderItem);
 if (item != null)
 {
     item.ChangeStock(order.NumberOfItems);    
 }
```

Comment: and what if there are multiple orderitems in stocklist? This would work only for first

Comment: There aren't multiple Orders in stockList.

Comment: oh, missed that line ^^

Comment: If there's only ever excatly one matching item, I would use `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault` if there can be zero matching items). This would make the intent clearer and throw an expection if there are more than a single matching item. If it's wrong if there are more than one matching item, you want to know it as early as possible.

Comment: I missed that line, too :-D

Comment: @DominicKexel, that's the issue to be discussed whether `Single` or `First` should be used here. This line can be simple viewed as the access to the collection and I would not input here control of the logic that only zero/one items should be matched (so exception will be thrown if more than one is found) - this can be controlled on some higher layer.

Answer (score 4):

```
stockList.FindAll(i => i == order.OrderItem)
.ForEach(i => i.ChangeStock(order.NumberOfItems));
```

Untested, just typed ^^

Comment: Works like a charm, although it needed one more parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Added the missing parenthesis